# Why does this transaction (truffle metacoin example) not require gas?

Tags: web3js, truffle, gas

In the truffle [metacoin example](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle-webpack-demo/blob/master/test/metacoin.js) why does this line not require {gas: xxxx}? Is it that this transaction doesn't need gas or that truffle sets some sort of default gas?

```
return meta.sendCoin(receiver, amount, {from: account});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly it's not truffle that sets the default gas value, but web3 itself (source: [web3 docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction), although it doesn't specify which value that is). You can verify that by checking the receipt from the sendCoin transaction in truffle and inspecting `txid.receipt.gasUsed` (where txid is the name of the receipt retrieved from the transaction).

Comment: ah I see: "defaults to the mean network gas price".